# How to restore VS project template for test if I deleted it by mistake?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, project-template

When I was installing some new templates for VS, I deleted built-in test project template by mistake. How can I restore it?

Comment: Did you check the recycle bin?

Comment: when I delete something, I don`t delete to the recycle bin - I don`t know whether it`s good or bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

devenv.exe /installvstemplates

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116.aspx

Comment: Some other suggestions: reinstall the latest SP; try "repair" option of installer; try "repair" option of installer, but run from original install media; try copying from another machine with a good install; if all else fails, try uninstalling and reinstalling